# pdf files for USPTO application

Tags: pdf

As I understand it, .pdf files are required for EFS USPTO submissions.

It seems that the well-heeled lawfirms have Adobe Acrobat to produce .pdf files.  That being said, has anyone had success filing USPTO NPA applications with free pdf applications?  If so please state the name of the tool.  Thank you

Comment: Apple computers can produce PDFs from pretty much any application without extra software.

Answer (score 2):

I have used CutePDF to "print to PDF" on a PC.

Comment: It’s probably good practice to inspect the accuracy of the pdf by reviews it in acrobat reader.